# Changing image source attribute with jquery doesn't work on IE

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change an image's source attribute with jQuery.
It works great on Safari and Chrome but doesn't work on Internet Explorer (v11)

code :

```
$('.ui360 a').on('click', function(){ 
$("#album-img").attr("src", $(this).data("src"));
});
```

html

```
<div class="ui360"><a href="track1.m4a" data-src="track-image-1.jpg">Track 1</a></div>
<img src="album-cover.jpg" id="album-img">
```

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your issue.What is suppose to do: `href="track1.m4a"` ???

Comment: I am using a jQuery plugin called Soundmanager. It's an audio player. It plays the track after clicking on the link.

Comment: add return false; after line .$("#album-img").attr("src", $(this).data("src"));

Answer (score 4):

Add return false; so that link will not redirect to href

```
 $('.ui360 a').on('click', function(){ 
    $("#album-img").attr("src", $(this).data("src"));
     return false;
});
```

I run this code in Internet Explorer (v11). Though your href is not looks good may be it will be track1.m4

Comment: So you should accept the answer and give the answer up vote :D

Comment: now image source is changed when it's clicked on but track doesn't play anymore :/